# Regular expression to isolate single letter variables in javascript, and ignore that letter when in a word

Tags: javascript, regex

As an exercise I like to de-obfuscate code submitted to tinycode competitions like [js1k](http://js1k.com).

One of the first things I do is try to rename the single-letter variables to something meaningful.

**Example**

```
  n = .6 * Math.random()
  h = "hsl(" + [200 + 80 * Math.random(), "100%", e + 20 * Math.random() + "%)"]
```

Is this case, `n` is a random number between `~0.06` and `0.6`. Let's rename it it `multiplierSmall`

I now want to find all instances of `n` to rename it, but I will be finding the letter "n" in "Math.ra**n**dom()", etc, with a standard CTRL+F.

I'm using sublime text which I believe supports regular expressions in it's search.

**EDIT**: Also consider the single letter variable may not necessarily have a space after it (`n = 10`) but is often next to an operator (`n<.5`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\b\w\b`

\b is the word boundary
\w is any 'word' character.

FOLLOW-UP EDIT (after OP uploaded snapshot):

How about `\b[a-zA-Z]\b`

hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks! That also captures number, but works just fine. Huge visual add (screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/9VwcCuE.png)

Comment: Thanks for feedback with uploaded picture.  I have updated my answer.  Should that be sufficient, please accept the answer.